# Magento Products Count Missmatch

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.7. From Admin panel product page shows more than 70k records. But when I try to get product count in a block by

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->count();
```

it shows only 10k count. Why the missmatch come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$productCount = count($this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->getData());
```

Comment: How I set in _prepareCollection() since only collection doesnot give all the rows.